# Type inheritance: Why do you have to create a new object instead of setting the prototype directly?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I try to understand the prototype-based inheritance in JavaScript. To establish a prototype chain with constructor functions, you usually do it this way:

```
function Person( name, gender ){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}

function Male( name ){
    Person.call(this, name, "male");
}

Male.prototype = Object.create( Person.prototype );

Object.defineProperty( Male.prototype, "constructor", {
    enumerable: false, value: Male, writeable: true
});

var person1 = new Male( "Chris" );
```

So, for `Male.prototype` you create a completely new object which has the internal [[prototype]] property set to the parent object. Because it is a new object, you still have to add a non-enumerable `constructor` property.

Since there is a way to set the `[[prototype]]` property directly, I wonder why you can't do this:

```
function Person( name, gender ){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}

function Male( name ){
    Person.call(this, name, "male");
}

Object.setPrototypeOf( Male.prototype, Person.prototype );

var person1 = new Male( "Chris" );
```

With this solution you just set the `[[prototype]]` property of `Male.prototype` to the parent object. (Before ES6 you could have used the `__proto__` property to set the prototype.)  You don't need to create a new object (because as far as I know the js runtime *automatically* attaches a new `prototype` object to  every function) and you don't need to create the correct `constructor` property explicitly, because it is already there.

My question is: why does nobody use this approach to set the prototype chain? Where is the problem?

Comment: FYI, your `Object.create` version can be done a little more cleanly by using the second argument to define the `constructor` property.

Comment: The `Object.defineProperty..` line isn't really the common way to set up the constructor. That whole instruction (those 3 lines) would just simply be: `Male.prototype.constructor = Person;`

Comment: @ScottMarcus: That makes it enumerable. Using `defineProperty` lets you set the correct property descriptor.

Comment: I understand what `defineProperty` buys me. I'm just saying that it is not strictly necessary for inheritance, nor was it the "common" way to do it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You need to make it non-enumerable or otherwise the `constructor`-property is listed in a `for in` loop. That is usually not desired.

Comment: @KaiGrunert As I said, I understand what `defineProperty` does. Having the constructor as non-enumerable is "usually not desired" is a matter of debate. I think it's much more common to just set the constructor property of the sub-type after changing the prototype and not worry about the enumerability of the property.

Answer (score 0):

That's a interesting question. I didn't know about the existence of the  setPrototypeOf method. Apparently the performance is worst than using Object.create

> If you care about performance you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using Object.create().

See more in the link from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/setPrototypeOf)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt a few days ago and I asked about it here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/343778/when-doing-inheritance-why-not-simply-modify-the-prototype-property-of-the

Apparently, there's no real consensus as to why we shouldn't do `Object.setPrototypeOf( Child.prototype, Parent.prototype )`, but there are general warnings thrown at us from Mozilla (MDN).

> Warning: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine. The effects on performance of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in obj.__proto__ = ... statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose [[Prototype]] has been altered. If you care about performance you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using Object.create().

Bottom line is: **don't do it!**

It breeds uncertainty in the code.

Answer (score -1):

This is a subtle but VERY important point. If you set the `Male` prototype to the `Person` prototype, **they will be sharing *ONE* instance of an object**. Any changes to the `Person` prototype will affect ALL instances of both the `Person` and `Male` objects ***and vice versa***. Now, initially, this seems like the desired behavior, but you have to keep the concepts of "types" separate from "instances" here.

By giving `Male` a ***new*** instance of `Person` as its prototype, you gain the benefits of inheritance, ***but you de-couple*** the actual instance of `Person` that all `Person` instances are using from the instance that all `Male` instances will use.

This allows you to make changes to the `Male.prototype` without affecting any `Person` instances.

Comment: *"If you set the `Male` prototype to the `Person` prototype..."* That would be true, except that that isn't what the OP is doing. The OP is switching the next item in the prototype chain of `Male.prototype`  from `Object.prototype` to `Person.prototype`, so on the surface it seems valid, but I don't know if this suffers the same performance issues of altering the prototype chain that way.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that in the general case, but this is a one time alteration of the prototype chain of the constructors themselves, not individual instances. I wouldn't want to make any claims either way without testing.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the answer. If I understand you correctly, I don't think you're right. Like squint said, this operation just connects the internal `[[prototype]]` property to get the correct prototype chain. `Male.prototype` and `Person.prototype` are still two different objects and not _one_ object.